# Update data of array json

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

MyTable

```
id |  data
___________
1  |[{"Session1": "", "DeviceId1": ""}, {"Session2": "", "DeviceId2": ""}]
```

I want update data and set Session1 equal to xxx and DevicceId1 eaqual to yyy

I write this query but this not worked

```
update MyTable data=jsonb_set(data, '{Session1}', 'xxx',true)
```

How can update value of array of json in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is a json array, so the path to `Session1` needs to be `{0,Session1}`, similarly `{0,DeviceId1}` for `DeviceId1`

Which would make the update statement:

```
UPDATE "MyTable"
SET "data" = jsonb_set(jsonb_set(data, '{0,Session1}', '"xxx"', true), '{0,DeviceId1}', '"yyy"', true)
WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: thank you for answer.if i want `select from mytable where data->>session1='xxx' and data->deviceid='yyy'` how should write this?

Comment: something like this: `select * from t 
where data#>>'{0,Session1}'='xxx' and data#>>'{0,DeviceId1}'='yyy'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a json array index (starting from 0) as a path:

```
update my_table
set data = jsonb_set(data, '{0}', '{"Session1": "xxx", "DeviceId1": "yyy"}')
where id = 1
returning *;

 id |                                     data                                     
----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | [{"Session1": "xxx", "DeviceId1": "yyy"}, {"Session2": "", "DeviceId2": ""}]
(1 row)
```